# How to display the sum of amount with between two given dates with groupwise, in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, query-builder

I want to display the customer name and its sum of all the bills he paid between specific dates. I also want the whole list of customers between the 2 given dates with sum of their total bills.

In list what I want is first Customer Name then its regarding sum of all the bill totals.

I have tried many options for it one where I am getting the sum of that bill only every bill is appearing separately while I want to group it by the customer thats all.

Raw query is working in phpMyAdmin but I failed to convert it to Laravel Eloquent. I want to make this raw query to work using Eloquent.

Query:

```
select customer_id,sum(total),sum(totalcgst),sum(totalsgst),
sum(totaligst) from sales where
date BETWEEN '2018-03-01' and '2018-03-31'
group by customer_id
```

[This is the result I am getting in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z5Ay.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried something with laravel elequent? what is the problem you're having doing it?

Comment: Also, do you have models? do those models have relationships set?

Comment: `DB::table($request -> get('reporttype'))->select('*')
                                ->from($request -> get('reporttype'))
                                ->whereBetween('date', array($request -> input('fromdate') ,$request -> input('todate')))
                                ->get();`
this is the laravel query i have created but after adding groupBy clause in it I am receiving error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORM_NAME::selectRaw('customer_id, sum(total), sum(totalcgst), sum(totalsgst)')->whereBetween('date', ['2018-03-01', '2018-03-01'])->groupBy('customer_id)->get();
```

Comment: it is giving me the only one bill detail of that particular customer not all the other bills total that he paid....

Comment: Thanks buddy i just did some change in date thats why its giving me the faulty result but now after fixing its working thanks.

Comment: You're Welcome :)